# How to upload capybara screenshots from gitlab runner to the Digital ocean cache?

Tags: digital-ocean, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running my rails tests using gitlab runner on Digital ocean servers.
I save bundler cache in the Digital ocean Spaces

Also I am using capybara-screenshot to make screenshots of the page when a test case fails.
When a test fails a screenshot is being saved to `./tmp/capybara/`

Then after the end of test run the build servers are deleted and screenshots are lost which makes investigation of the test failure a lot harder.

Is there a way to upload the contents of the `./tmp/capybara/` folder to Digital ocean Spaces using the key and secret which gitlab runner uses to retrieve/upload the cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use job artifacts to save any data created by the build step. the files will be shown at right side of the build step.

in your case:

```
your_build_step:
  ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./tmp/capybara
    when: always
    expire_in: 1 week
```

Read more about it here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html

Comment: Thanks for the help @Amityo, but seems like that job artifacts are saved only after successful job run. I don't see job artifacts for the failed jobs, but I can see them for the successfully finished jobs

Comment: seems like `when: always` does the job when a job has failed

Comment: thanks @Hirurg103 . if you want artifacts only on failures you can also use: `when: on_failure`